# A question about the eigenvactors of positive semi-definite matrices

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite

Assume that $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is a Hermitian positive semi-definite matrix and $z\in\mathbb{C}^{n}$ such that $z\neq 0$. If $z^*Az=0$, is it true to conclude that $z$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated with eigenvalue $0$?

Comment: Is $A$ symmetric?

Comment: Not if $z=0$, and even if $z\neq 0$, the only possible eigenvalue you can get is $0$.

Comment: May be that is exactly what he wants, finding the eigenvectors associated with $0$ ?

Comment: More to the point, the vector $z=0$ is not an eigenvector, but satisfies $z^*Az=0$. So the conclusion is wrong without further assumptions.

Comment: If you assume $z\ne 0$, then you are correct.

Comment: @ A. Pongrácz, $A$ is Hermitian.

Comment: @Kusma, Yes, you are right. The point you mentioned has now been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

This is true. Using diagonalization we can construct a positive semi-definite matrix $B$ such that $B^{2}=A$. Then $z^{*}Az=\|Bz||^{2}$ so we get $Bz=0$ which implies $Az=0$.

Comment: How is $z^{*}Az=\|Bz||^{2}$ ? I think it would have been true if $B^*B=A$.

Comment: @nicomezi For complex scalars  $A$ positive semi definite implies $A=A^{*}$. This is a standard fact in operator theory (but this is not true for real scalars).

Comment: I know, but my doubts are about having $B^2=A$. $A$ being a positive definite complex matrix is equivalent to having $B$ such that $B^*B=A$, not $B^2=A$. Furthermore, if you have $B^2=A$, the link between $z^*Az$ and $\|Bz\|^2$ is not clear.

Comment: @nicomezi $B$ is also positive semi-definite, so what is difference between $B^{2}$ and $B^{*}B$?

Comment: Nothing indeed. I am really tired these days.